# Mysql Select query with double JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hy guys. I need to select the customer_id who is on 'base' table, where the created date is the current date and where this customer dont have a budget_item executed on the current date. My query brings up an incorrect result. It show the customer_id of all budget_id that are not on that date..

What is wrong in my stetement?

PS.: I cannot consolidate the tables.

```
SELECT base.customer_id 
FROM base
LEFT JOIN budget ON base.customer_id = budget.customer_id
LEFT JOIN budget_item ON budget.budget_id = budget_item.budget_id
WHERE 
     CAST(base.created as Date) = CURDATE()
     AND budget_item.execution_date <> CURDATE();
```

[image]

Comment: consolidating the tables would be a very wrong thing to do, so it is good that you cannot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join budget/budget_item specifically looking for items with the current date and then exclude them in WHERE by checking that some non-nullable column of budget_item is NULL (indicating no record was joined):

```
SELECT base.customer_id 
FROM base
LEFT JOIN budget ON base.customer_id = budget.customer_id
LEFT JOIN budget_item ON budget.budget_id = budget_item.budget_id AND budget_item.execution_date = CURDATE()
WHERE
     CAST(base.created as Date) = CURDATE()
     AND budget_item.budget_id IS NULL;
```

Some prefer using NOT EXISTS for this, but the result and efficiency should be the same:

```
SELECT base.customer_id 
FROM base
WHERE
     CAST(base.created as Date) = CURDATE()
     AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM budget
         JOIN budget_item ON budget.budget_id = budget_item.budget_id AND budget_item.execution_date = CURDATE()
         WHERE budget.customer_id = base.customer_id
     );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7569b6cf2ed9c24dc9f89cae0a24fb5b)

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT base.customer_id 
FROM base LEFT JOIN
     budget bu
     ON base.customer_id = bu.customer_id LEFT JOIN
     budget_item bi
     ON bu.budget_id = bi.budget_id
WHERE CAST(base.created as Date) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY base.customer_id
HAVING SUM(bi.execution_date = CURDATE()) = 0;
```